# New to Java and I am attempting to program a Project Euler Q with recursion

Tags: java

In this problem I tried to reproduce Project Euler results in Java but, ultimately I have given up after several failed attempts and hours of work. The program compiles but, I have no idea why it won't go through my if statements. This is not for a class but, for myself. Here is project Euler's Prompt: "If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23."

Here is my attempt:

```
public class MultiplesOfThreeandFive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int x = 3; 
        int y = 10; 
        if (y > 0) {
            if (y % x == 0) {
                System.out.println(y + " is a multiple of 3");
                y--;      
            } else {
                System.out.println(y + " is not a multiple of 3");
                y--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your last paragraph is particularly likely to get you a nice response...

Comment: I don't frankly care. There are hundreds if not thousands of forums. I will create a new account on this or another website. As far as I know there is no ip or mac-address locking on this or other websites. I asked for help last time and instead was bullied in comments instead of getting help. I told my last Java teacher it is why I like python more because the community is nicer and there is also a help method built in with built in easy to understand documentation.

Comment: hello I ran your original code and it ran fine. the if statements executed

Comment: Yes but, it only produces 1 result. How do I get it to run through the entire loop?

Comment: okay i will help you with this give me a minute okay

Comment: @Espryon Regardless of your past experience, I don't believe coming back passive-aggresively insulting the community is really the right way to start on a new foot. In any case, there's *plenty* of documentation and *tons* of tools out there. If you haven't noticed already, showing a lack of willingness to thoroughly look for a solution before posting is one of the ways you don't get a good reception.

Comment: Hello You may need to study some 'while' 'for' loops a little bit more.

Comment: also please mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: @Espryon I removed your second question from this one. You are much more likely to get downvoted or have your question closed if you post 2 questions in one, or post additional meta information which isn't related to your question. Note that Stack Overflow isn't a forum, but a Q&A site and things that aren't questions or answers belong in comment only. You should be able to ask a separate question though for your other question and get a separate answer.

Comment: Hi @Espryon, I think you need to read up about Loops and Recursion in Java more. The code you have supplied doesn't have any loop in it and it definitely doesn't have any recursion. Project Euler is a great place to improve your algorithmic skills but perhaps it is not a good place to start learning how to program if you don't already know the basics.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NewClass2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int y = 1;   
        while(y<=23){
            int x = 3; 
            if (y > 0) {
                if (y % x == 0) {
                    System.out.println(y + " is a multiple of 3");
                    y++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(y + " is not a multiple of 3");
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

You need to use a while loop to and increment y. Notice I put y++ after each if satement?
While y is under or equal to 23 it will continue to loop. Try this code.

Comment: please mark this as correct by clicking the correct symbol.

Comment: @JohnHogan, why do you continue your loop until 23?

Answer (score 0):

public class MultiplesOfThreeandFive {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 3;
    int sumOfAll = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)  {

        if(y % x == 0)  {
            System.out.println(y + " is a multiple of 3"); 
            sumOfAll = sumOfAll + y;
            System.out.println("Sum is " + sumOfAll);
        } else {
            System.out.println(y + " is not a multiple of 3");

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: btw recursion is when a method calls on itself

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MultiplesOfThreeandFive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i+" is a multiple of 3 or 5");
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is : "+sum);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the question clearly, but why are you not incrementing the value of Y, like in a loop, seems like the value of Y stays constant, is that what you want?

Comment: I'm just trying to get it to go through a loop and it seems very difficult to get the program to do this.

Comment: public class MultiplesOfThreeandFive {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x = 3;
  for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)  {
   
   if(y % x == 0)  {
    System.out.println(y + " is a multiple of 3");                     
            } else {
                System.out.println(y + " is not a multiple of 3");
               
   }
  }

 }

}